# how to align children in a angular material row vertically

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

The html is build with the layout directive (layout="row") and contains an icon and 3 select boxes. My select boxs and icon is NOT aligned - how can I alignment these horizontally ?

My code

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="start center" class="filter"> 
        <div flex="15">
            <i class="material-icons md-24">filter_list</i>Filter
        </div>
        <div>
            <md-select ng-model="$ctrl.selectedtype1" placeholder="type1" class="md-no-underline">                    
                <md-option ng-repeat="type in $ctrl.type1List" ng-value="type">
                    {{type.value}} ({{type.id}})
                </md-option>
            </md-select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <md-select ng-model="$ctrl.selectedtype2" placeholder="type2" class="md-no-underline">                    
                <md-option ng-repeat="type in $ctrl.type2List" ng-value="type">
                    {{type.value}} ({{type.id}})
                </md-option>
            </md-select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <md-select ng-model="$ctrl.selectedtype3" placeholder="type3" class="md-no-underline">                    
                <md-option ng-repeat="type in $ctrl.type3List" ng-value="type">
                    {{type.value}} ({{type.id}})
                </md-option>
            </md-select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

...looks like this:
[image]

Comment: vertically or horizontally?

Comment: Should have been "horizontally" in my question.

Answer (score 0):

https://plnkr.co/edit/I8Jn4JweN0OVGBzBAwS8?p=preview

```
material-design-iconic-font css provides many icons. Try this plunkr:
```

Comment: Thanks for your code share. But what I'm looking for is a way to make the selectbox text aligned with the text. So in this case "Filter" has to be aligned with "type1" in the selectbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use md-icon tag provided by angular material.

Following are the related links:

1.https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdIcon

2.https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/icon

Filter should be added in between md-icon close and open tags in a span